# Laravel Eloquent one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, one-to-many, relationship, eloquent, laravel-3

I am having real problems getting Laravel's Eloquent ORM to return data for a relationship.

## My migrations (database schema):

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->create();

    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('firstname');
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password')->unique();
    $table->string('phone')->nullable();
    $table->text('about')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('files', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->create();

    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('filename');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->string('keywords')->nullable();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('file_type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

## Models

### File.php

```
<?php

class File extends Eloquent
{

    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

}
```

### User.php

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->has_many('File');
    }
}
```

### routes.php

```
// everything else in my routes.php is as it was when downloaded
Route::get('users', function()
{
    echo '<pre>';

    // this works
    $users = User::all();
    print_r($users);

    // this doesn't work
    print_r($users->files);

    // this doesn't work
    $files = User::find(1)->files;
    print_r($files);
});
```

## Errors:

> Unhandled Exception
>
> Message:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object
>     Location:
>
> C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\application\routes.php on line 51
>     Stack Trace:
>
> #0 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\laravel\laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\wamp\www\l3_...', 51)
>     #1 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\application\routes.php(51): Laravel{closure}(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\wamp\www\l3_...', 51, Array)
>     #2 [internal function]: {closure}()
>     #3 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\laravel\routing\route.php(163): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
>     #4 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\laravel\routing\route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
>     #5 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\laravel\laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
>     #6 C:\wamp\www\l3_mlib\public\index.php(34): require('C:\wamp\www\l3_...')
>     #7 {main}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turns out you cannot have a model called `File` as it conflicts with an internal Laravel module. I renamed the `File` model and table to `Upload` and everything works now.

Comment: I did exactly this with 'Event' as a model name yesterday, didn't realise it was reserved :)

Comment: Is there a list of reserved words for Laravel anywhere?

Comment: Hmm.. I haven't found one, but looking down the Namespaces and Class list in the API Docs is a good start: http://laravel.com/api/ - You'd also need to be aware of the names of any Bundles and Libraries you were using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with a model called Task which is a Laravel class also.

In application/config/application.php there are some class aliases that remove the namespacing. You can comment out the File alias, then it will not clash with yours.

If you then need to use the Laravel File class at any point, you can refer to it via its namespaced name, e.g.

`Laravel\\File::get('path/to/file');`

Hope this helps,

Dan

Comment: For SEO: I had the same issue, when using a class named `Response`, giving me `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::all()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your migration schema, you did not set up the foreign key, so laravel cannot get the object data, when using

```
 $files = User::find(1)->files;
```

and thats why, it returns, error: Trying to get property of non-object Location

add this to your files migrations and see if it works

```
 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->unique('user_id', 'files_user_id');
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

and you can use namespaces to avoid the conflict on class names